# Find start and end points of a group of numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search

I have an array of 288 values. it contains ones and zeros in a group in any combination.

e.g

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0.1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0...]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1....]
```

it can start and end either by a group of zero or a group of one. but it is guaranteed that in the array it will have at least one group of zeros or ones. My interest is to store the indexes of the start and and end of group of ones in an array. e.g 6,16,23 in first example in start_index (lets say this is the vector to store) and 11,19 in end_index.

I want this to be generic. as my array can start from any group.

i am using the following code to implement this but I am unsuccessful in implementing the complete logic.Whenever I think I am stuck how to make the algo. The code below is the small portion I have written which only deals with the one possibility.

```
std::vector<float>start_index
std::vector<float>end_index

float alter_value = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
    if (alter_value == 0)
    {
        if(array[i+1] != alter_value)
        {
                start_index.push_back(array[i+1]);
                alter_value = array[i+1]; // this makes my alter_value = 1
        }
    }
}
```

May be I am unalbe to convey in a better manner what I want. But I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for a `1` in the array, once it is found, record its location and skip through all the adjoining 1s. Once you hit a zero, you can continue doing the same thing over again (look for the next `1`).

The edited code looks as follows. Also note some changes in the declaration.

```
std::vector<int> start_index
std::vector<end> end_index
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == 1)
        {
                    start_index.push_back(i);
                    while(array[i] == 1 && i < array.size()) {
                       i++;
                    }
                    //will reach here if array[i] == 0 or array is exhausted
                    end_index.push_back(i - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you mentioned end_index.push_back(i - 1);. should it not be end_index.push_back(i);?

Comment: @MT When you break out of the loop, `array[i] is equal to 0`, you need to record the location of last `1`, which is `i - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store indices, but you store array values instead.  Indices are integers, so your index vectors must be `vector<int>`, and instead of

```
start_index.push_back(array[i+1])
```

you have to do

```
start_index.push_back(i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way :)

```
    int last = array[0];
    start_index.push_back(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array[i] != last) {
            start_index.push_back(i);
            last = array[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider following algorithm. It's in pseudo code - I'm not C++ fan, but rewrite it to any language should be trivial:

It loops thru the whole input and detects the edges of groups, storing them in result* arrays.

```
array; // input array
resultStarts; // array of indexes of starts of groups
resultEnds; // array of indexes of ends of groups
searchFor = 1; // element of groups

inGroup = false;

for(i=0;i<length(array);i++) {
 if((array[i] == searchFor) && ! inGroup) {
  // it's start of group
  inGroup = true; // mark it
  push(resultStarts, i);
 }
 if(inGroup && ((array[i] != searchFor) || i == length(array))) {
  // end of group (of the input)
  inGroup = false;
  push(resultEnds, i);
 }
}
```